# PHP spin system. The lower the number is, the more rewards you get

Tags: php

Okay I have kind of a spin system, you spin and it generates a random number.

If the number is less than 100, you will win.

But how can I make it so, the lower the number his, the higher coins you will get

Currently i have this:

```
    public function getPrize($number)
    {
        $prize = $number * 250 / 2;     

        if ($number < 100)
        {

            return '<span style="color: green;">You have won lucky  <b>'.$prize.'</b> coins!</span>';
        }
        else
        {
            return '<span style="color: red;">Sorry but, bad luck. You have won nothing! number: '.$number.'</span>';
        }
    }
```

$prize is the prize. Basically now I am multi piling it by 250 and dividing by 2. so if I get the number '1'. i will get an awful prize.

How do I do that?

Comment: `$prize = (100 - $number) * 250 / 2; `

Comment: What is the purpose of dividing 250 with 2? It is 125 always!

Comment: Take a look at my answer - it is shorter and maximum prize is easily readable - in my example it is 125. However despite unneeded division, @MarkBaker`s answer is also good.

Comment: I think most did misunderstood my question, not sure though. What I want is, the less generated lucky number you get, will get you more REWARD COINS. for example my generated number is 99, I will get 250 coins (which is minimum), and if I get the number 1, I will get 1000 coins which is the maximum.

Comment: It is possible to make if statements OR cases switch, but it's so ghetto to do, I am sure there is a method to loop through all instead of using multiple if statements or cases switches

Comment: @JonyKale, I have edited my answer. Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with a little of thinking and calculation.

***1000 - 250 / 100 = 7.5***

```
$prize = 250 + (750 - ($number * 7.5));
```

Results:

x(1) = 1000

x(100) = 250

Comment: Good job! Better than mine. In my solution, you got -72 for 55, because I forgot to wrap `99.00 - floatval($number)` with braces. Sorry, I was testing my algorithm with Python, as it has interactive interpreter, thus it is considerably faster to test algorithm this way. Then I translated it to PHP with missing braces, so you got the bug :(

Comment: x(1) = 250 + (750 - (1 * 7.5)) = 250 + 750 - 7.5 = 992.5 not 1000 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Final version:

```
if($number < 100){
    $prize = round((99.00 - floatval($number)) * 7.653) + 250;
else{
    $prize = 0;
}
```

This gives 250 for `$number = 99` and 1000 for `$number = 1` as author desires.

Comment: For those who think it is surprisingly complex, please read all @JonyKale requirements added in comments. He wants exactly these values for 99 and 1.

Comment: Will the value of the coins for number 55 be highter than the value of coins of the number 56?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. I will try to adjust this.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function float() in /home/driptone/public_html/jony/applications/luckyspin/includes/class/Luck.class.php on line 67

Comment: It was a typo - should be `floatval` not `float` ;)

Comment: Ok I've tested it out, but it returns -72 if I use the number 55.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  Just takes the opposite of the number using a maximum.

```
function getNumPrizes($number)
{
    $maxPrizes = 100;

    // using max so we dont get less than 0
    $prizesWon = max(($maxPrizes - $number) + 1, 0);

    return $prizesWon;
}
```

This way you'll end up getting 100 coins for a 1, 99 for a 2, etc.

You could then run $prizesWon through another function to scale it how you wish.

Comment: Also good but linear. From his code I guess he wants geometrical incrementation of prize.

Comment: Well I want it so the less number you get, the more coins you will earn. so if you got the number 50, you will get 500 coins, and if you get the number 1, you will get 1000 coins. sort of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.

```
   function getNumPrizes($number)
 {
    $maxPrizes = 100;
    $multiplier = // number you want to multiply with the result. It may be 125 or something else

    // using max so we dont get less than 0
    $prizesWon = max(($maxPrizes - $number) + 1, 0)*$multiplier;

    return $prizesWon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll try this way:

```
public function getPrize($number)
{
    $quad = $number*$number;

    if ($number<100 && $number>0)
    {
        $prize = 0.0525665*$quad-12.885*$number + 1012.83; //http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic+fit+%281%2C1000%29%2C%2850%2C500%29%2C%28100%2C250%29
        return '<span style="color: green;">You have won lucky  <b>'.$prize.'</b> coins!</span>';
    }
    else
    {
        return '<span style="color: red;">Sorry but, bad luck. You have won nothing! number: '.$number.'</span>';
    }
}
```

**edit.**

I've found a function which gives the expected results for the given numbers. Hope it's ok.
Data source: [Wolphram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic%20fit%20%281,1000%29,%2850,500%29,%28100,250%29)

Comment: Don't have time to test this now - but should work with proper factors - I believe your factors are correct. Have a look at mine answer after last edit. Cheers.

Comment: The main difference between our answers is that you're using linear function and I'm using a `quadratic` function.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to define a math function f(x) where f(1) = 250 and f(99) = 1000;

there are lots of possible shapes which will.

i suggest you graph the results of your functions to help you decide what is best for you.

here are some examples.

```
// linear growth
// this produces a straight line
function prize($number) return (101 - number) * 75 + 250;  


// log growth
// this produces a log curve where you have diminishing returns
function prize($number) return (log(101 - number) -1 ) * 750 + 250;

// exp growth
// this returns exponential returns
function prize($number) return (((101-number)^2)/10000) * 750 +250;
```

the basic operations here are you have a function which generates a values for the series between 1-100.

1. invert the input (101-number) so that smaller inputs produce bigger results.
2. map the output to your scale... which is between (0 to 750) by multipling 750 by a ratio.
3. translate your scaled number to 250 which is your minimum

Comment: "function f(x) where f(1) = 250 and f(99) = 1000;", exactly but different.

f(1) = 1000 and f(100) = 99. I need to find out what is f(55), f(96) and etc automatically by using a formula or functions.